# Elastic Beanstalk Server Logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an application hosted in AWS in Elastic Beanstalk. The environment runs ok, but sometimes I get an error message: "The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.". Where are the server logs that this message refers to?

I looked at Elastic Beanstalk => Environment => Logs but they don't have anything related to the cause of the error.

Comment: ssh to the EB instance and search for logs in `/var/logs`.